# Input source of Text entry Ubuntu 15.04 unavailable

Tags: 15.04, ibus, input-method

I've installed the ibus-unikey package, but I can't use Vietnamese (Unikey) (Ibus) Method. It's **not available**. I tried to remove and reinstall the package, but this problem remains.

[image: screenshot showing input sources and terminal after ibus restart]

Is there any way to fix it?!

Answer (score 1):

My friend installed Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit. Then he installed Vietnamese (Ibus) (Unikey). There's no problem with his computer.

I think the cause of my problem was updating my Ubuntu from an older version to 15.04. The system reported some error, so I tried to restart my computer and continued the update.

After reinstalling 15.04, this problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log out and log in again.

*Edit:*

I now understand from your comment that you did. Then the next advice would be to open *System Settings -> Language Support* and make sure that the selected "Keyboard input method system" is **IBus** (and relogin if you need to change it).

Comment: After install the ibus-unikey package, I tried restarting my computer, but it not works.

Comment: @AnhNguyễnNgọc: Just edited my answer, adding another idea.